# Bootstrap 3: Stack cols only when screen size is less than 500px

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want the bootstrap to stack the columns only when the device size is less than 500px, but the below code stacks them after I reach the extra small threshold which is 768. How can I change that?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class=" col-sm-4">
  1
  </div>
  <div class=" col-sm-4">
  2
  </div>
  <div class=" col-sm-4">
  3
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the less file variables

change

```
screen-sm-min = 768px
```

to

```
screen-sm-min = 500px
```

If you want small devices in general (default < 768px ) You could use

```
class=" col-sm-4 col-xs-12"
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Thanks Sven, is it a wise idea? May it have unpredictable affects laters?

Comment: No screen-sm-min is a variable that is used in a less file to set the col-sm size, when compiled to css it is converted to the pixels you've set. It's the recommended method by bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

you are using col-sm it is for small devices, instead of col-sm use col-xs might be it fix your concern.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class=" col-xs-4">
  1
 </div>
 <div class=" col-xs-4">
  2
 </div>
 <div class=" col-xs-4">
  3
</div>
```

Comment: When I use `col-xs` then the columns always stay next to each other, they don't pile up.

Comment: Also col xs = <768 not <500